# How to make Ionic close side-menu on click from popup button?

Tags: angularjs, button, popup, ionic-framework

i've been modifying my popup menu inside side menu for a while in ionic framework, and trying to close the side menu on click from the button i've created in the popup. Are there any possible way to do so ?

Answer (score 7):

```
function ContentController($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
}
```

Comment: Thx @Aaron Saunders , I misplaced the toggleLeft in my code before, that's why it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

For close menu:

```
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(false);
```

code from ionic:

[image]

[image]